# API 'search' method with 'tagged' parameter

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, api, search

From [the docs](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=search) for `tagged` paremeter:
*List of tags delimited by semi-colons of which at least one must be on a question*

Yet, when I execute [this query](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/search?tagged=java;algorithm&sort=creation&min=1296897084&pagesize=2) (`http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/search?tagged=java;algorithm&sort=creation&min=1296897084&pagesize=2`), it returns a single 8-hours old question, tagged **both** algorithm and java. Naturally, since that time lot's of newer questions has been posted in both `algorithm` and `java` tags separately.

It looks like, current interpretation of this parameter is **each one must be on a question** instead.

Comment: Hmmm.... this *does* look like a bug.

Comment: I noticed that today too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a gotcha porting /search over to Lucene with tag searching.

Should be fixed now.